# Retrieve the nth value of a char-delimited string in one-line

Tags: java

How can I retrieve the nth value of a char-delimited string in one line?

If the string was `'.'` delimited, and I wanted to take a string `a.b.c` and retrieve `c` in Python, I would simply do:
`'a.b.c'.split('.')[-1]`.

Seemingly, the equivalent in Java is:

```java
String beforeSplit = "a.b.c";
String[] parts = beforeSplit.split("\\.");
String afterSplit = parts[parts.length - 1];
```

Is there a way to consolidate this into a one-line expression without using intermediate variables/strings to store the `parts`? e.g.:

```
String consolidated = 'a.b.c'.split("\\.")[this.length -1];
```

After doing some experimenting, it doesn't seem like `this` is an operable way to refer to the preceeding result's return value, in one line.

I suspect this would result in an ugly closure of some form but maybe there's an easier method that I am not aware of?

Comment: @Robert I am familiarizing myself with Java - there isn't a strong need/requirement here, just curious to see if it was possible to retrieve the nth value of a char-delimited string in one line that wasn't apparent to me at first sight. The objective was to do so dynamically, so a hard-coded index would not be an operable substitute.

Edit: I think your first comment is the answer to this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spontaneously I can't think of an elegant one except replacing using regex:

```
String lastPart = "a.b.c".replaceAll("^.*?([^\\.]*)$","$1");
```

or using lastindexOf

```
String lastPart = "a.b.c".substring("a.b.c".lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

`split` returns an array, and until it returns that, you cannot find its length, which you need to know to find the last element. There is no -1 index for the last array element in Java. So you could duplicate the `split` logic:

```java
String consolidated = "a.b.c".split("\\.")["a.b.c".split("\\.").length - 1];
```

which is ugly and error prone, especially if the `split` argument gets more complex. You could pull that out into a variable, but then your original code would IMHO still be clearer.

If you know you always want the 3rd field, you could hard-code that as `'a.b.c'.split("\\.")[2];` but that may defeat the purpose of splitting in the first place.

Java can feel heavily object-oriented compared to Python. But if you have some domain object (like an IP address or inventory number that follows a certain scheme), it may make sense to create a new class for this:

```java
public class Split {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Split s = new Split("a.b.c");
        System.out.println(s.last());
    }

    private String[] values;

    public Split(String input) {
        values = input.split("\\.");
    }

    public String last() {
        if (values.length == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        return values[values.length - 1];
    }
}
```

Now the invocation is shorter, plus if you can come up with a clearer (i.e. more business-domainish) name than `last`, the code is also clearer than the pythonic splitting and negative indexing.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... How can I retrieve the nth value of a char-delimited string in one line? ..."*

You'll need two *Strings*; not that intuitive.

```java
String a, b = (a = "a.b.c").substring(a.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
```

Or, use a *regular expression pattern*, and the *[String#replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String))* method.

```
.+\.
```

```java
String s = "a.b.c".replaceAll(".+\\.", "");
```

> *"... it doesn't seem like `this` is an operable way to refer to the preceeding result's return value, in one line. ..."*

The *this* keyword is similar to the *Python* *[self](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)* keyword.
It provides a reference to the enclosing instance.

*[Using the this Keyword (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Classes and Objects)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)*.

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static String getKthItem(String str, int k) {
    return str.split("\\.")[k];
}
```